Get column name from a variable in snowflake
How to get a column name from a variable?
I was trying this but did not work
set a = 'aaa';
select 1 as $a ;


I suspect what you're really after is a way to select a specific column by storing that column name to a variable. If so...here's what that would look like. If not, let me know, I'll delete the answer
create or replace temporary table t (col1 varchar);

set col_name = 'col1';
select identifier($col_name)
from t;


yes, that did work for me

Snowflake doesn't directly support dynamic column names within a single SQL statement. However, there are a few workarounds like UDF , Stored procedure to achieve this, which is not very straightforward.
One of the simpler option would be to use SnowSQL like below

Create a sql script(dynamic_column.sql)

    SET a = 'aaa';
    
    SELECT 1 AS :a;


Execute the script from terminal

    snowsql -f dynamic_column.sql

